# How to speed up large test-suite run duration using pytest?

Tags: python, performance, pytest, test-suite

I have a `pytest` test-suite which contains over 30,000 test cases. When I run it, it takes over 10 hours to run.

However, when I cut the number of test cases down to 1,000, it completes in 39 seconds!

Any idea on what is going on here? The test cases are very simple, just calling one function which is doing no I/O (no network calls, DB calls etc).

Any help would be great!

Best,

Dave.

Comment: How do you expect anyone to give you an answer? It could be any of a whole bunch of reasons. I'd suggest just running the full suite and timing execution of every test.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was the size of the test files. After splitting the test cases across multiple smaller files, there was a huge increase in speed!